# Spitting out the Most Played Song(s) from a List

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

How would you write a code that allows the user to compare every song in a list and return the song that is mostly played? Also, if there are more than one song with the maximum number of plays, how do you display all?

Here's what I have so far:

```
case 5:
        boolean max = false;
        int mostPlays = 1;
        song = new Song(artist,title);

        for(int i = 0; i < songCollection.size(); i++)
        {
        song = songCollection.get(mostPlays);
        if (songCollection.get(i).getNoPlays() < song.getNoPlays())
        {
        songCollection.get(mostPlays).getTitle();
        mostPlays++;
        max = true;
        }
    else
        {
        mostPlays++;
        }
    }

    while (max)
        {
        System.out.println(song.getTitle());
        }
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the list by number of plays, descending.
2. Start at beginning, display song, save number of plays.
3. Go to next song, display if number of plays is the same, stop if not. Repeat.

Relavent docs:

[Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

[Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (used for sorting)